# Android: Is there a way to have lollipop press animation with jellybean min sdk

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.2-jelly-bean, rippledrawable

---

I'm currently writing an android app. I want the minimum sdk to support jelly bean devices, so I set the min sdk to 17. Everything works, but the pressing animation on buttons and etc. are all the older animations. Is it possible to have the new lollipop circle animation? Or at least have it on 5.0 devices.

If you need anything, comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean ripple effect. There are several libraries that can handle ripple : [traex/RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect), [siriscac/RippleView](https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView) and [balysv/material-ripple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) all supporting API14 and up from what I can see.

If you wish to use whole material components, not just ripple I'd recommend [rey5137/material](https://github.com/rey5137/material) or [navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary). Those contain material design buttons, switches and much more ready to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look at these.